# Javascript recursive function issue

Tags: javascript, hierarchy, kendo-treeview

I am trying to create a function that will loop over a Hierarchy of arrays and concat them together. I am struggling to think of a way to do this.

I call a Web API that returns me some data which has the same properties and layout but can differ in how many Hierarchy layer array there is.

**Folders: A folder can contain 'Routes' but can also contain another folder inside of it which can then also contain more 'Routes' etc**

**Routes: A single object which is a route.**

For example:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "folders":[
      {
         "id":2,
         "folders":[
            {
               "id":3,
               "folders":[],
               "routes":[]
            }
         ],
         "routes":[
            {
               "id":1002,
               "name":"Route3"
            },
            {
               "id":1003,
               "name":"Route4"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "routes":[
      {
         "id":1000,
         "name":"Route1"
      },
      {
         "id":1001,
         "name":"Route2"
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to be able to keep going deeper into the hierarchy and concat all of the Routes arrays with the Folders array, so I can bind the Kendo TreeView with a single child which will be the Folders array.

So far I have tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Folders.length; i++) {
    if (Folder[i].Folders.length > 0) {
        for (var e = 0; e < Folder[i].Folder[e].length; e++) {
            if (Folder[i].Folders[e].length > 0) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with that method is that I will never know how many layer there will be and therefore is not a viable method.

The result I need is the above example to look like:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "folders":[
      {
         "id":2,
         "folders":[
            {
               "id":3,
               "folders":[

               ],
               "routes":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "id":1002,
               "name":"Route3"
            },
            {
               "id":1003,
               "name":"Route4"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":1000,
         "name":"Route1"
      },
      {
         "id":1001,
         "name":"Route2"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You should probably update your question with the sample json and required output, so that it's easy to understand

Comment: Did you tried it already? show us the code that you already have and ask question in which part you have troubles.

Comment: @DDRamone Sorry, I have added what I have so far.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well

Comment: @AnuragSinghBisht Sorry, I am unsure what you mean. I have added the JSON that I am getting. I will update my question with the JSON that i need now.

Comment: @NinaScholz Will add now.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have edited the question.

Comment: @AnuragSinghBisht I have edited the question.

Comment: Input and Output JSON looks the same to me

Comment: @AnuragSinghBisht As you can see there are no Routes properys as the objects have been concatenated into the folders array.

Comment: why does the result contains a `routes` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var flatRoutes = function(folders){
  for(var i in folders){

    var cur = folders[i];
    if(cur.hasOwnProperty('folders')){
      flatRoutes(cur.folders);
    }
    
    if(cur.hasOwnProperty('routes')){
      for(var i in cur.routes){
        cur.folders.push(cur.routes[i]);
      }
      
      delete cur.routes;
    }
    
  }
  
  return folders;
}
  

var json = {
   "id":1,
   "folders":[
      {
         "id":2,
         "folders":[
            {
               "id":3,
               "folders":[],
               "routes":[]
            }
         ],
         "routes":[
            {
               "id":1002,
               "name":"Route3"
            },
            {
               "id":1003,
               "name":"Route4"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "routes":[
      {
         "id":1000,
         "name":"Route1"
      },
      {
         "id":1001,
         "name":"Route2"
      }
   ]
}


var routes = flatRoutes([json]);

console.log(routes);
```

Comment: This is the example how to use recursive function when you don't know how deep is it. Hope it will help

Comment: In the routes array you have created it doesn't seem to have the folder (the one with ID = 3) it would need to contains all the folders as well in that routes array.

Comment: Good to hear that. In that case don't you mind to accept the answer? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a `property` from ab `object`, you can make use of `delete object.property`.

I have taken the following step, I think it gives the correct result.

- Create a `modular` function - `formatData`
- Check if `folders` array has any data or not
- If `folders` array have data, call `formatData` for every `folder` in it
- Then, check for the `routes` array. If no routes, return the `data`
- If `routes` array have data, just push each `route` into the folder array and `remove` the `routes` property from the object.

```js
let data = {
  "id": 1,
  "folders": [{
    "id": 2,
    "folders": [{
      "id": 3,
      "folders": [],
      "routes": []
    }],
    "routes": [{
        "id": 1002,
        "name": "Route3"
      },
      {
        "id": 1003,
        "name": "Route4"
      }
    ]
  }],
  "routes": [{
      "id": 1000,
      "name": "Route1"
    },
    {
      "id": 1001,
      "name": "Route2"
    }
  ]
};

function formatData(data) {
  if (data.folders.length) {
    data.folders.forEach(folder => {
        return formatData(folder);
    });
  } 
  if (data.routes.length) {
    data.routes.forEach(route => {
      data.folders.push(route);
    });
    delete data.routes;
  }
  return data;
}

console.log(formatData(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach.

```js
var data = { id: 1, folders: [{ id: 2, folders: [{ id: 3, folders: [], routes: [] }], routes: [{ id: 1002, name: "Route3" }, { id: 1003, name: "Route4" }] }], routes: [{ id: 1000, name: "Route1" }, { id: 1001, name: "Route2" }] },
    result = [data].map(function iter(o) {
        return {
            id: o.id,
            folders: (o.folders && o.folders.map(iter) || []).concat(o.routes || [])
        };
    })[0];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```